# how to load different frontend modules templates in backend for customizing templates contents using symfony 1.4,doctrine

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

how to load different frontend modules templates in backend for customizing templates contents

I have class module in frontend & also templates as well.
I have also created a module in backend as emailcontent for accessing several modules templates
to customize html.
 1. How do i access/Load templates in backend module emailcontent

Answer (score 4):

I think you are asking how do you use the same code in the frontend and the backend, but customising the templates?

If so the solution you are after it to create a plugin which in enabled in the front and the backend then over write the templates as you would say the sfGuardPlugin.

Have a look at the Jobeet example for creating plugins: http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/20